# PIC18F46K22, led blink not working

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I bought a PIC18F46K22 and I am trying to light a LED, but it doesn't work. The same code works on PIC16F887. I read the datasheet, but I can't see any difference between ports for the 2 microcontrollers. What am I doing wrong?
The code is shown below, thank you in advance!

```
int main(){
TRISB=0x00;
PORTB=0x00;
  while(1){
    PORTB=0XFF;
    Delay_ms(1000);
    PORTB=0X00;
    Delay_ms(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the config fuses (in particular, the bits related to the oscillator choice) set to something that matches your hardware?

Comment: I am new to PIC, can you explain me what you are telling? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're probably not setting the PIC analog pins to digital mode.

On most (if not all) PIC chips with analog inputs, analog capable pins will ALWAYS start up in "analog mode".  Before you can use them as digital outputs, you need to set them to "digital mode"

Refer to the datasheet [HERE](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001412G.pdf) and take a look at the ANSELx registers.  If your LED is on port B as your code implies, you will need to write 0 to the corresponding bits ANSELB to set the pins as digital.
ANSELB = 0x00;
will set all Port B pins as digital.

Also, when writing output pins, it is best practice to write the latch rather than the port register.
LATB = 0xFF;

General rule of thumb is LATx to write outputs, PORTx to read inputs.

Comment: In general, pins set to analog input can still output digital but cannot input digital. But +1 for LATx, it has bitten many newcomers including myself when I started out.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in a comment, make sure you set your configuration bits to match your actual hardware. Pay particular attention to the oscillator configuration as the code wont run without an active oscillator (if in doubt, use the internal oscillator).

If your oscillator is running, make sure that the pin(s) your monitoring are not shared with an active hardware peripheral that is taking control of the pin (ex. UART, PWM,...).